# Left align ol numbers with the heading in the same “column”

Tags: html, css, list, alignment, html-lists

For the sake of simplicity, I've put everything in the HTML part:

```html
<section style="text-align:center;">
  <h3>FRUITS</h3>
  <ol>
    <li>Apples</li>
    <li>Bananas</li>
    <li>Oranges</li>
  </ol>
</section>
```

How to make every number of `ol` to be aligned by the same "column"?

I would like to get this:

```
FRUITS
1. Apples
2. Bananas
3. Oranges
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For left align the list numbers with the heading.

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
}
section {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
ol {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
ol li {
    counter-increment: step-counter;
}
ol li:before {
    content: counter(step-counter)". ";
}
```

```html
<section>
    <h3>FRUITS</h3>
    <ol>
        <li>Apples</li>
        <li>Bananas</li>
        <li>Oranges</li>
    </ol>
</section>
```