# How to horizontally align the numbers of ol items to their contents

Tags: html, css, html-lists

The numbers of the list are moving according to the text length of the `li`, causing the vertical align to drop. Notice that I have styles the numbers, as you can see in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/cmfL2643/23/).

I tried to use a span, but I couldn't get it working.

```css
li span { 
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ol class="rounded-list center_ol">
    <li class="cool_white"><a href=""><span>Yannis Drogitis</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="cool_white"><a href=""><span>Dimitris Mariglis</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="cool_white"><a href=""><span>Kots Mariglis</span></a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

How to make the numbers align vertically, in respect to every other number in the list?

---

Not to be confused with this question: [Left align ol numbers with the heading in the same “column”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33219983/left-align-ol-numbers-with-the-heading-in-the-same-column)

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283285/css-is-there-a-way-to-vertically-align-the-numbers-bullets-before-each-list-ele) is a similar question. Hope you would like it. (y)

Comment: Isn't that the same attempt I have made @Irshad? I am looking it into. -some minutes later-Yeap, it didn't do the trick! :/

Comment: @gsamaras Do you mean [this](http://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/cmfL2643/25/)?

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/cmfL2643/31/?

Comment: @divy3993 the list is not centered.

Comment: @Vitorinofernandes that's nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As looking to your comments, i think this might help you, but one thing is bit sloppy here that is you need to mention specific width for `<a>` elements, if you try my solution.

**[Working : Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/cmfL2643/33/)**

**Snippet Below:**

```css
ol.rounded-list {
    counter-reset: li;
    /* Initiate a counter */
    list-style: none;
    /* Remove default numbering */
    *list-style: decimal;
    /* Keep using default numbering for IE6/7 */
    font: 15px'trebuchet MS', 'lucida sans';
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 4em;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
.rounded-list a {
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block;
    width:125px;
    text-align:left;
    background:;
    margin:0px auto;
}
.rounded-list a:before {
    content: counter(li);
    counter-increment: li;
    position: relative;
    left: -1em;
    top: 64%;
    margin-top: -1.3em;
    background: rgba(255, 168, 76, 0.5);
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    border: .3em solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 2em;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
}
.center_ol {
    text-align: center;
    list-style-position:inside;
    width:60%;
    margin:0px auto;
    border:1px solid red;
    
}

.cool_white
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: .4em;
    border-radius: .3em;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
    border:1px solid green;       
}
```

```html
<h3 class="center_ol">Man-to-man suggestions</h3>

<ol class="rounded-list center_ol">
    <li class="cool_white"><a>Yannis Drogitis</a>

    </li>
    <li class="cool_white"><a>Dimitris Mariglis</a>

    </li>
    <li class="cool_white"><a>Kots Mariglis</a>

    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Your solution is very good.In which situation would the sloppy point harm me?

Comment: Glad that it helped you. What i meant here was, you need to give **specific `width`** if you don't do so, it will be of no use. Nothing else.

Comment: Oh OK divt. BTW, I am having a hard time with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725501/leftover-hover-effect-on-touch . If you want, take a look!

Answer (score 4):

It seems it was inheriting unwanted properties. from li.cool_white. I implemented these CSS base from the link suggested by Irshad.

*Updated*

I have modified my old code. Instead of `body` I have created a new class called `.outer` where any element here would be centered and anything outside would not be.

```
.center_ol {
    text-align: left;
    list-style-position:inside;
}

.outer {
    text-align:center;
}

.list{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
```

[Updated Results](http://jsfiddle.net/cmfL2643/34/)

Comment: That's good. However, I would like only the list to be centerized, not the whole `body`. Can you do something about it?

Answer (score 2):

If you change your `center_ol` rule like this, is yet another way to solve it.

An update of your [fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/cmfL2643/36/)

```
h3.center_ol {
    text-align: center;
}
ol.center_ol {
    list-style-position:inside;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that `text-align: center` is not mandatory. Simply remove this rule from your elements.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cmfL2643/27/).

If you did, however, want to center the elements, just wrap all the elements in a container (`div`) - and use a `translateX` to align the element `center` without needing to mess with `width` sizes. It also doesn't rely on `text-align: center` to position the elements. [Check out the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/cmfL2643/32/).

```css
ol.rounded-list {
    counter-reset: li;
    /* Initiate a counter */
    list-style: none;
    /* Remove default numbering */
    *list-style: decimal;
    /* Keep using default numbering for IE6/7 */
    font: 15px'trebuchet MS', 'lucida sans';
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 4em;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
.rounded-list a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: .4em .4em .4em 2em;
    *padding: .4em;
    margin: .5em 0;
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: .3em;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
}
.rounded-list a:before {
    content: counter(li);
    counter-increment: li;
    position: relative;
    left: -1em;
    top: 64%;
    margin-top: -1.3em;
    background: rgba(255, 168, 76, 0.5);
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    border: .3em solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 2em;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
}
.center_ol {
    list-style-position:inside;
}

div {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

body {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h3 class="center_ol">Man-to-man suggestions</h3>
    <ol class="rounded-list center_ol">
        <li class="cool_white"><a>Yannis Drogitis</a>

        </li>
        <li class="cool_white"><a>Dimitris Mariglis</a>

        </li>
        <li class="cool_white"><a>Kots Mariglis</a>

        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: This list is no longer in the center.

Comment: @gsamaras updated the fiddle to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cmfL2643/32/) - it now will be position horizontally centered without `text-align: center`

Comment: @shubhamr238 the code is included in the answer, without the need for the external links - click *Show code snippet*